# Set of Tools to optimize the performance in general of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I know there are things out there to help to optimize queries, ect... but is there anything else, something like a full package that can scan your database and highlight all the performance issues, naming conventions, tables not properly normalized, etc?

I know this is the job of a DBA and if the DBA is good, he shouldn't need a tool like that, but sometimes you start a new job, you get in charge of an existing database and the DB is a mess, so you don't know where to start...

Thanks to everyone

Dave

Comment: While I'm dubious about being able to accurately detect a lack of normalization, naming conventions are a maintenance concern, not a performance concern.

Comment: The short answer to this is definitely "no"! :-) (This is, after all, what makes being a DBA interesting!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion a normalized database does not guarantee good performance. Normalization is concerned primarily with data consistency.

It's not really practical for an automated tool to handle what you are proposing because there is no one case fits all implementation for best practice, which after all is to be treated as more of a guideline. That's why businesses hire people like me to take an objective look at their unique SQL Server environment (shameless plug).

The performance aspect can be addressed either by the wealth of features already available in the SQL Server product or by off the shelf tools such a those from Quest/Redgate and the like.

If you want to get a quick overall feel for the performance of a new SQL Server box that has come under your administrative control then I suggest either using the freely available Performance Dashboard Reports or SQL Server DMV's. You could also take a look at the current Wait Types on the server.

- [SQL Server 2005 Performance Dashboard
  Reports](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1d3a4a0d-7e0c-4730-8204-e419218c1efc&displaylang=en)
- [SQL Server Wait Type Example](http://www.johnsansom.com/index.php/2009/12/sql-snippet-wait-types/)
- [How to identify the most costly SQL
  Server queries using DMV’s](http://www.johnsansom.com/index.php/2009/05/how-to-identify-the-most-costly-sql-server-queries-using-dmvs/)

I hope this answers your question and do let me know if I can assist further.

**Edited in response to comment:**

Maybe a general Health Check could provide useful info.

- [SQL Server Best Practice
  Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=da0531e4-e94c-4991-82fa-f0e3fbd05e63&displaylang=en)

Comment: It answers my question. Basically I wasn't looking for a tool to fix performance issues in a database, but more an information tools to display potential problems with the DB.

Thanks for your quick answer

Comment: @Dave: Perhaps the SQL Server Best Practice Analyzer could prove useful to you.